# Unable to create Epic using JIRA cloud REST API (C#)?

Tags: c#, json, jira, jira-rest-api

I am working on a requirement where I need to create an 'Epic' issue type first and then I need to create a 'Bug' issue type mentioning the Epic name in it.

I am parsing the following data for adding an Epic in JIRA but its giving me an error:

```
string json = @"{""fields"":{""project"":{""key"":""SITBIT""},""summary"": ""Test Epic"",""description"": ""Test Epic Description"",""issuetype"": {""name"":""Epic""}}}";
```

The above code is giving me the below error:

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

The above JSON code is working fine for normal issue type however its throwing an error if I changed the Issue type to 'EPIC'.

What could be the issue? How can I parse the JSON so that the epic can be added.

Secondly, When I am parsing the already added Epic name in the normal issue type then also it gave me (400) bad request error.

Comment: Isn't there a more detailed message error?

Comment: The code is giving an exception is "{"The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."}".

Comment: Try use Insomnia or other REST client to check it. Usually there is a more detailed error message in the response.

Comment: The 400 Bad Request usually occurs when there is an error with the JSON data.

Answer (score 1):

Different issue types can have different required fields. To create an epic you also need to specify the 'Epic Name', but this field is missing in your request.

You can use the JIRA REST API to verify which fields are required using the /rest/api/2/issue/createmeta resource:

> The fields that can be set on create, in either the fields parameter or the update parameter can be determined using the `/rest/api/2/issue/createmeta` resource. If a field is not configured to appear on the create screen, then it will not be in the createmeta, and a field validation error will occur if it is submitted.

The [JIRA REST API documentation](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/#api/2/issue-createIssue) also contains more info about how errors are handled. You only mention the message that corresponds to the status code of the response, but the response body will contain more info, for example:

`{
    "errorMessages": [
        "Field 'priority' is required"
    ],
    "errors": {}
}`